# Select only one single class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Says I have multiple of class named item.

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

But I only want to show one, sequence doesn't' matter. How do I do that?

```
$('.item').show() // this will show all of them
```

Comment: And which one should be shown? What 'sequence' are you talking about? IMHO, it is unclear what it is asked here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any of the following methods to choose a particular element from the matched set:

```
// show the first .item only  
$('.item:first').show();
$('.item').first().show();

// show the last .item only
$('.item:last').show();
$('.item').last().show();

// show the second .item only
$('.item:eq(1)').show();
$('.item').eq(1).show();
```

Note that `eq` takes a parameter which is the index of the element you want to target.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.item').eq(0).show() // it will display first item
```